Helmholtz equation in a metal waveguide channel
I have a problem with the concept of solving the Helmholtz equation in a metal waveguide channel. An example in which I encountered a contradiction was that we have a waveguide channel with dimensions $a$, and $b$, which emits light in the $\hat z$ direction in the $TM$ mode. As we expect, we have $E_x, E_y, E_z, H_x$ and $H_y$ waves, and we have to calculate them. Now, if we want to define the Helmholtz equation, can we define it for $H_y$ and then solve it with Maxwell's equation to get the rest, or should we start with $E_z$ as a base? (I did not understand the same point in the three electromagnetism books by Cheng, Griffiths, and Rao, why we should start from $E_z$.)

hint: the $E_z$ component is special because you know its boundary conditions independently of the other components, can you you see why?

@hyportnex The boundary conditions are the same as, for example, at the boundary of the x-axis and the wave must be zero, but my main problem is why they use the Ez wave.

hint #2: Griffiths (4ed) Equations (9.180) show that in a homogeneous guide $E_z$ and $H_z$ together determine all the other components and if the wave is TM then what is $H_z$?

@hyportnex When we are in TM mode, the Hz wave will be zero, but we have Ez, but why should we start from Ez?

@hyportnex  I once read the points you said, one question for our propagation we need Ez and Hz waves because we propagate in that direction, now since we are in TM mode, then Hz becomes zero and only Ez remains, did I understand correctly?  One more question, I just looked at another book, Elements of Photonic by iizuca, the second volume, which examines this issue for two parallel pages, and its mode is TM, so why did he examine the issue with Hy?

In a homogeneous (both longitudinally AND transversally) waveguide there are only two independent unknowns. Look at Griffiths 9.180 and understand it, if $H_z$ is zero then only $E_z$ remains to be found. I do not understand your 2nd question regarding "parallel pages". Anyhow, try to understand Griffiths.

@hyportnex Yes, that's right, thank you, just a side question, can't we consider the independent variable instead of Hz and Ez, for example, two components in the y direction, because I think they should not be different

Maxwell's equations are not independent, and despite having 6 unknown $E,H$ components there are only 4 of them independent. In a waveguide that can further be reduced to two unknown functions. These happen to be the $E_z$ and $H_z$ components. If you pick another pair of functions then you may have the problem if their equations and their boundary conditions are indeed separable one from another. It is not enough to say that $E_y$ satisfies Helmholtz, to solve for it you also need to know its BC that contains only this component. You know that $E_y|{y=0}=0$ but what should $E_y|{x=0}$ be?
